# Why is my imageview shrinking while I'm scrolling my tableview cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm dynamically resizing my label, which is in my tableview cell. The number of cells appearing in a view is fine. But while I'm scrolling the new cells are having the big size of the image view. Please let me know why.

Here is code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 { 
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell"; 
   TVcell *cell = [tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   if (cell == nil) 
      cell = [[TVcellalloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

   cell.titleLabel.text = [[[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"title"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet‌​:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
   cell.txtlabel.text = [[[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"description"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
   cell.IMGLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
   [cell.IMGLabel sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[enclosureUrlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0]; 
   [cell.IMGLabel.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];    
   [cell.IMGLabel.layer setCornerRadius:2.5f];
   [cell setNeedsLayout]; 
   return cell; 
 }
```

Comment: could you please share your code so can find problem.there may one case is due to reusable cell  recalculate label size that may create problem.Observe label size every time cell create.Please share your code so we can find actual problem.

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    
    TVcell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    if (cell == nil)
    
        cell = [[TVcell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
   cell.titleLabel.text = [[[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"title"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Comment: cell.txtlabel.text = [[[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"description"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];   
cell.IMGLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[cell.IMGLabel sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[enclosureUrlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];
 [cell.IMGLabel.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
 [cell.IMGLabel.layer setCornerRadius:2.5f];
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    return cell;
}

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it's unreadable. You should [edit] your question instead.

Comment: added code from comment to question

Answer (score 0):

## For that please share your code.

## Note:

- Make sure that the cell is registered or not and set proper
  constraints for the image view and label to get the proper listing in
  tableview.